# alternative to using import static strings?

Tags: java, android

I am currently using `import static package.name.here.MainClass.string;` in my ui handler to update textviews, and send strings to my "log" textbox.

I am now able to `string.setText("text")` in my uiupdate thread class.

My question is, is this safe way to handle updates to textview/send text logs(just multiline textbox)?

If not what would be recommend/safe way to update UI?

Comment: What do you mean by textbox here? Android doesn't have textbox, but instead EditText or TextView with custom background.

Comment: I meant TextView, sorry I do some C# programming, but not too often. Java has been keeping me hooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that using static at any View is a good idea. Because it will keep the reference of the View. If the View is inside an Activity, the Activity itself will not garbage collected even if it already stopped. There are some ways to notify UI from a background thread/different component of your application. You can use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), publish/subscribe event bus([Otto](https://github.com/square/otto), [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)), or observable pattern([RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava), [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/Rxandroid))

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will check out some examples.

Comment: Feel free to accept as an answer if it resolve your problem